# Section-level equation numbers follow previous section numbering

Tags: math-mode, equations, numbering

I am using `\numberwithin{equation}{subsection}` to number my equations uniquely for each subsection in my article.

For example:

1. Section 1 Title

1.1 Subsection 1.1 Title

a=b  (1.1.1)

a+2=b+2 (1.1.2)

2. Section 2 Title

r=y   (1.0.1)

However, in my document, I am not getting the right equation number for the first equation in the new section. The actual equation number sequentially follows the equation from the previous section. From the example above, r=y would be numbered 1.0.3.

Equations in the subsections below section 2 (i.e. 2.1 with equation 2.1.1) are numbered correctly.

Shouldn't the sections re-set the counter automatically?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Inferring/guessing what your code may be doing, I am unable to produce an equation number "1.0.1" for the third equation ("r=y"). Instead, I get "2.0.3". Please post your code so that pointless guesswork may be eliminated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the instruction

```
\numberwithin{equation}{subsection}
```

you need the instructions

```
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{equation}{section}
\makeatother
```

The first instruction, `\numberwithin{equation}{subsection}`, resets the equation counter only when a `\subsection` instruction is encountered. If you have a `\section` instruction but no `\subsection` instruction, the counter named `equation` is *not* reset unless you provide an additional instruction, such as `\@addtoreset{equation}{section}`.

[image]

Do note that if you do want to number the equations by subsection, it's probably *not* a good idea to feature equations between a `\section` directive and that section's first `\subsection` instruction: at that stage, the `subsection` counter is still `0` (having been reset to `0` by the `\section` directive), leading the equation numbers to be formatted as "2.0.1" and quite likely making your readers wonder if the subsection numbered `2.0` has somehow vanished mysteriously.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath} 
\numberwithin{equation}{subsection} 
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{equation}{section}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1 Title}
\subsection{Subsection 1.1 Title}

\begin{equation} a = b \end{equation}
\begin{equation} a+2=b+2 \end{equation}

\section{Section 2 Title}
%%\subsection{Subsection 2.1 Title}

\begin{equation} r=y \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You also can do it with the  `changcntr` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{chngcntr}

\counterwithin{equation}{section}
\counterwithin{equation}{subsection}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1 Title}
\subsection{Subsection 1.1 Title}

\begin{equation} a = b \end{equation}
\begin{equation} a+2=b+2 \end{equation}

\section{Section 2 Title}

\begin{equation} r=y \end{equation}

\subsection{Subsection 2.1 Title}

\begin{equation} r + s=y + z\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]